# Fast index of lower upper bound in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the index of the lower upper bound in R.
This is the same problem that findInterval resolves, but findInterval checks if it's argument is sorted, and I want to avoid that, because I know that it is sorted.
I'm trying to call the underlying C function directly, but I'm confused on whether I should call findInterval or find_interv_vec.
Also, I try to make the call, but can't seem to find the function

```
findInterval2 <- function (x, vec, rightmost.closed = FALSE, all.inside = TRUE) 
{
    nx <- length(x)
    index <- integer(nx)
    .C('find_interv_vec', xt=as.double(vec), n=length(vec),
       x=as.double(x), nx=nx, as.logical(rightmost.closed),
       as.logical(all.inside), index, DUP = FALSE, NAOK=T,
       PACKAGE='base')
    index    
}
```

I get

```
Error in .C("find_interv_vec", xt = as.double(vec), n = length(vec), x = as.double(x),  : 
  "find_interv_vec" not available for .C() for package "base"
```

On the other hand, I read that it is better to use .Call than old .C, specially because .C copies, and my vec is really big. How should I structure the call to .Call?

Thanks!

Comment: your code works for me - `R 2.15.1`

Comment: Do you think not checking that `vec` is sorted will make your calls that faster? How long will `x` and `vec` be in your application?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213029/more-efficient-strategy-for-which-or-match)?

Comment: @flodel I'm dealing with `length(vec) > 30k`, do you think that it doesn't matter? (that's a question, not irony)

Comment: If @MartinMorgan answered your question in his linked answer could you extract which method of his timed functions you used as an answer and mark it this as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and the very helpful answer of @MartinMorgan I decided to do something similar to his answer.
I created some functions which emulate findInterval, without checking if vec is sorted. Clearly this makes a big difference when x is of length 1 and you call it over and over again. If x is of length >> 1 and you can take advantage of vectorizacion, then findInterval only checks once if vec is sorted.
In the following code chunk I created some variants of find interval

- findInterval2, which is findInterval written in R as a binary search without the sortedness chek
- findInterval2comp, which is findInterval2 compiled with cmpfun
- findInterval3, which is findInterval written in C as a binary search compiled with the inline package

After that, I created 2 functions to test

- testByOne, which runs findInterval for x of length 1
- testVec, which uses vectorization

For testVec, all the functions I created were vectorized in the x argument with Vectorize.

After that, I timed the execution with microbenchmark.

Code

```
require(inline)

# findInterval written in R as a binary search
findInterval2 <- function(x,v) {
  n = length(v)
  if (x<v[1])
    return (0)
  if (x>=v[n])
    return (n)
  i=1
  k=n
  while({j = (k-i) %/% 2 + i; !(v[j] <= x && x < v[j+1])}) {
    if (x < v[j])
      k = j
    else
      i = j+1
  }
  return (j)
}

findInterval2Vec = Vectorize(findInterval2,vectorize.args="x")

#findInterval2 compilated with cmpfun
findInterval2Comp <- cmpfun(findInterval2)

findInterval2CompVec <- Vectorize(findInterval2Comp,vectorize.args="x")

findInterval2VecComp <- cmpfun(findInterval2Vec)

findInterval2CompVecComp <- cmpfun(findInterval2CompVec)

sig <-signature(x="numeric",v="numeric",n="integer",idx="integer")
code <- "
  if (*x < v[0]) {
    *idx = -1;
    return;
  }
  if (*x >= v[*n-1]) {
    *idx = *n-1;
    return;
  }
  int i,j,k;
  i = 0;
  k = *n-1;
  while (j = (k-i) / 2 + i, !(v[j] <= *x && *x < v[j+1])) {
    if (*x < v[j]) {
      k = j;
    }
    else {
      i = j+1;
    }
  }
  *idx=j;
  return;
  "

fn <- cfunction(sig=sig,body=code,language="C",convention=".C")

# findInterval written in C
findIntervalC <- function(x,v) {
  idx = as.integer(-1)
  as.integer((fn(x,v,length(v),idx)$idx)+1)
}

findIntervalCVec <- Vectorize(findIntervalC,vectorize.args="x")

# The test case where x is of length 1 and you call findInterval several times
testByOne <- function(f,reps = 100, vlength = 300000, xs = NULL) {
  if (is.null(xs))
    xs = seq(from=1,to=vlength-1,by=vlength/reps)
  v = 1:vlength
  for (x in xs)
      f(x,v)
}

# The test case where you can take advantage of vectorization
testVec <- function(f,reps = 100, vlength = 300000, xs = NULL) {
  if (is.null(xs))
    xs = seq(from=1,to=vlength-1,by=vlength/reps)
  v = 1:vlength
  f(xs,v)
}
```

Benchmarking

```
microbenchmark(fi=testByOne(findInterval),fi2=testByOne(findInterval2),fi2comp=testByOne(findInterval2Comp),fic=testByOne(findIntervalC))
Unit: milliseconds
    expr        min        lq     median         uq       max neval
      fi 617.536422 648.19212 659.927784 685.726042 754.12988   100
     fi2  11.308138  11.60319  11.734305  12.067857  71.98640   100
 fi2comp   2.293874   2.52145   2.637388   5.036558  62.01111   100
     fic 368.002442 380.81847 416.137318 424.250337 474.31542   100
microbenchmark(fi=testVec(findInterval),fi2=testVec(findInterval2Vec),fi2compVec=testVec(findInterval2CompVec),fi2vecComp=testVec(findInterval2VecComp),fic=testByOne(findIntervalCVec))
Unit: milliseconds
       expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
         fi   4.218191   4.986061   6.875732  10.216228   68.51321   100
        fi2  12.982914  13.786563  16.738707  19.102777   75.64573   100
 fi2compVec   4.264839   4.650925   4.902277   9.892413   13.32756   100
 fi2vecComp  13.000124  13.689418  14.072334  18.911659   76.19146   100
        fic 840.446529 893.445185 908.549874 919.152187 1047.84978   100
```

Some observations

- There must be something wrong in my C code, it can't be that slow
- It's better to compile and then vectorize, that to vectorize and then compile
- It's weird that fi2comp runs faster than fi2
- Compiling again a vectorized compiled function doesn't increase its performance