# Why is the R match function so slow?

Tags: r

The following should find the location of the first instance of the integer `1`:

```
array <- rep(1,10000000)
system.time(match(1,array))
```

This returns

```
   user  system elapsed
  0.720   1.243   1.964
```

If I run the same task using an array of size `100` I get this:

```
   user  system elapsed
      0       0       0
```

Since all it should be doing is looking at the first value in the array and returning a match, the time taken should be that of a lookup and a comparison, regardless of the size of the array. If I wrote this in lower-level language it would cost in the order of a handful of clock cycles (a microsecond or less?) regardless of the array size. Why does it take a second in R? It seems to be iterating through he whole array...

Is there a way for it to abort once it has found its match, rather than continuing to iterate unnecessarily?

Comment: This question might be worth a read: [More efficient strategy for which or match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213029/more-efficient-strategy-for-which-or-match/16224331)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that R is not actually doing linear search, but it sets up a hash table. This is effective if you are searching for several items, but not very effective if you are searching for one number only. Here is the profiling of the function:

[image]

A "better" implementation could use a linear search, if you are searching for a single integer in an array. I guess that would be faster.

Comment: Cool, thanks for clearing that up :) Do you know of away of using this "efficient" method in R?

Comment: No, I am not sure if it is implemented in core R. But it is easy to implement a linear search. You would need to do it in C/C++, because R loops are slow. This is very easy using the Rcpp package, see the Rcpp gallery for examples.

Comment: From the question I linked above, @mnel suggests `which.max(array == 1)` as a potential time saver

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, I guess that is *almost* a linear search in C. It still goes over the whole array, though.