# Speedproblems by using apply in a function to translate multiple strings

Tags: r, apply

I wrote a little function `dictTranslator` to translate multiple strings into abbreviations or group them into categories... I use a `list` as a dictionary and have a data frame column with abbreviations and I want a column category with the related category name.

```
dictTranslator <- function(x, dict) {
  sapply(x, function(a) {
    result <- names(which(sapply(dict, function(b) {a %in% b})))
    if(identical(result, character(0))) {
      warning(sprintf('NAs are introduced, "%s" not found!', a), call.=FALSE)
      NA
    } else {
      result
    }
  })
}

my_dictionary <- 
  list(embryo=c('00h','01h','02h','e02','03h','04h','05h','06h','e06',
                '08h','10h','12h','e12','14h','16h','18h','20h','e20'),
       larvae=c('L1','L2','L3e','L3l'),
       pupae=c('p1','p2','p3','p4','p5'),
       adult=c('vm','m','vf','f'))
```

**sample data:**

```
df <- data.frame(abbreviation=rep(unlist(my_dictionary), 30000))
nrow(df)
# [1] 930000
system.time(df$category <- dictTranslator(df$abbreviation, my_dictionary))
```

The function works as expected but the performance is pretty slow (about a minute). Has anyone an idea to speed this up or is there maybe a better solution to this?

The result looks like:

```
> head(df,40)
   abbreviation category
1           00h   embryo
2           01h   embryo
...
19           L1   larvae
20           L2   larvae
21          L3e   larvae
22          L3l   larvae
23           p1    pupae
24           p2    pupae
25           p3    pupae
26           p4    pupae
27           p5    pupae
28           vm    adult
29            m    adult
30           vf    adult
31            f    adult
32          00h   embryo
33          01h   embryo
34          02h   embryo
35          e02   embryo
36          03h   embryo
```

Comment: I am not sure why people did not like my answer below :(  I explained it a bit more. With your example it takes less than 0.1 secs in my laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `match` on a named vector, plus removal of the numbers generated by unlisting `my_dictionary` (for which I used `sub`). This way you can avoid costly loops.

```
x <- unlist(my_dictionary)
df$category <- sub('\\d+$', '', names(x)[match(df$abbreviation, x)])
```

Run time is less than a second:

```
df <- data.frame(abbreviation=rep(unlist(my_dictionary), 30000), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
system.time({df$category <- sub('\\d+$', '', names(x)[match(df$abbreviation, x)])})
#   User      System     elapsed 
#  0.634       0.003       0.639
```

Comment: Hm, your idea is not working in my case, because the original data is random and not ordered like in my sample data where I just repeated the values of my dictionary.

Comment: @drmariod, can you update your example input to reflect that accurately?

Comment: Ok, I have to remove my comment, your code is completely correct... I didn't tested it before but I had the feeling something is wrong. But I like your code the most in the end :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest another data format for dictionary, also use `data.table` library:

```
library(data.table)

md <- list()
for(i in 1:length(my_dictionary)) {
  md[[i]] <- data.table(abbreviation = my_dictionary[[i]], category = names(my_dictionary[i]))
}
md <- rbindlist(md)
```

Then you simply join:

```
df <- data.table(df, key = 'abbreviation')
df <- df[md]
```

**Comparison**. I did ran a comparison of three approaches and here are the results:

Data preparation:
@docendo-discimus and @fdetsch use same data format

```
md1 <- unlist(my_dictionary)
df1 <- df
```

@danas.zuokas uses

```
library(data.table)

md2 <- list()
for(i in 1:length(my_dictionary)) {
  md2[[i]] <- data.table(abbreviation = my_dictionary[[i]], category = names(my_dictionary[i]))
}
md2 <- rbindlist(md2)
df2 <- data.table(df, key = 'abbreviation')
```

Here are three functions to compare

```
f_dd <- function(x, y) { x$category <- sub('\\d+$', '', names(y)[match(x$abbreviation, y)]); x } #docendo-discimus
f_dz <- function(x, y) { x <- x[y]; x } #danas.zuokas
f_fd <- function(x, y) { x$category <- gsub('\\d', '', sapply(x$abbreviation, function(i) names(which(i == y)))); x } #fdetsch
```

And here are the results

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f_dd(df1, md1), f_fd(df1, md1), f_dz(df2, md2), times = 10)

Unit: milliseconds
           expr       min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
 f_dd(df1, md1) 1041.9195 1142.8361 1236.2033 1224.498 1266.9600 1469.7119    10
 f_fd(df1, md1) 7106.6641 7417.5538 7924.3541 7868.716 8304.7760 8961.2615    10
 f_dz(df2, md2)   35.6389   41.7524   77.2347   63.478   70.1699  183.9867    10
```

Comment: You are growing an object (`md`) in a loop, which is usually not a good idea (not efficient) - it's better to preallocate. (Plus, the `data.frame` calls may also be costly)

Answer (score 0):

I found this approach finished fastest on my machine. Note that the input data is `character` which results in speed gains when compared with `factor` input.

```
## non-factor sample data
my_dictionary <- unlist(my_dictionary)
df <- data.frame(abbreviation = rep(my_dictionary, 30000), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

system.time({
  ## names
  result <- sapply(df$abbreviation, function(i) {
    names(which(i == my_dictionary))
  })

  ## discard numbers
  df$category <- gsub("\\d", "", result)
})

#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.993   0.000   3.991
```

As regards the code you provided (i.e., using multiple `sapply` loops in combination with `%in%`), keep in mind that `%in%` (or `match`) perform rather poorly when you are searching for a single entry (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923071/why-is-the-r-match-function-so-slow)).

Comment: Interesting note on the bottom of your answer. Did you look at my answer using `match` for the time comparison? It suggests that `match` in this case performs a lot better than an `sapply` loop.

Comment: True, but I'd guess using `match` or `%in%` inside an `sapply` loop - which the bottom note is clearly referring to - performs considerably worse.

Comment: Besides @docendodiscimus, yours is a perfect example for the capabilities of R if its vectorization possibilities are exploited consequently! Thanks for pointing out this solution.

Answer (score -2):

I will use a named vector for this:

```
a2c <- c ("larvae", "larvae", "larvae", "pupae", "pupae", ...)
names (a2e) <- c ('L1','L2','L3e','p1', 'p2', ...)
```

In your case you can easily build the vector doing:

```
a2c <- rep (names (my_dictionary), times = sapply (my_dictionary, length))
names (a2c) <- unlist (my_dictionary)
```

Make sure they match:

```
cbind (names (a2c), a2c)
```

And then:

```
df[,"category"] <- a2c[df$abbreviation]
```

In your example df$abbreviation is a factor so you may need to turn it into character

```
df[,"category"] <- a2c[as.character (df$abbreviation)]
```