# Is there a more efficient version of match for searching repeated permutations of numbers?

Tags: r, optimization, indexing, match

I have a dataset with 20 rows and n columns. I was originally working with n=10000, but have found that I need to use a much bigger number instead, probably over ten times as much. Each column of this dataset is generated independently of the others and contains a random but biased permutation of the whole numbers from 1 to 20. I wish to sum the locations of each number over the entire dataset. In other words, I want to know how many times the number a appeared in the bth position for every a and b (i.e. my final result is a 20*20 table of values).

I am confident that I already have code that achieves this goal. For example, my computer handles the entire n=10000 cause in under two minutes (i.e. it gives me the count for every single a and b). However, both n=100000 and the lesser n=50000 took so long that my patience ran out. Most of my code is extremely simple, and I am confident that the inefficiency is in the use of `match` in the following lines (`a`, `b`, and `n` are as described above, `data` is the dataset):

```
list<-c()
  for(k in 1:n)
  {
    position<-match(a, data[,k])
    list<-c(list,position)
  }
  return(sum(list==b))
```

how can I improve this? `match` [appears to be notoriously slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24923071/10319707), but all of the solutions that I've seen ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16213029/10319707)) are neither general solution nor applicable to this case.

If you wish to benchmark your solution `replicate(n,sample(20))` will generate a similar list to my dataset.

Comment: Hi J. Mini, it would be easier to help if you provide working code that produces the expected results.

Comment: @IanCampbell That seems like an unnecessary complication. I've isolated it to the lines that I strongly believe to be the only relevant ones and have given what I believe to be adequate context. The alternative would increase the amount of code in this question many times over and the additional required context would potentially confuse the issue.

Comment: I disagree, having the expected result offers the opportunity to use an orthogonal technique and easily validate the result, as @chinsoon12 shows.

Comment: What @IanCampbell is saying is you need to give an example of what is `a` , what is `b` and show what output you get from `sum(list==b)`. No need to increase even a single line of code just define `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the major bottleneck is you are increasing the size of the vector in the loop. Try to initialize it before the loop and assign the value in the vector.

```
list_vec <- numeric(length = n)

for(k in 1:n) {
  list_vec[k] <- match(a, data[,k])
}
```

Or using `sapply`

```
sapply(data, function(x) match(a, x))
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, these two blocks of code aren't equivalent. Perhaps you wanted ```apply(data, 2, function(x) match(a, x))```?

Comment: `apply(data, 2, fn)` is equivalent to `sapply(data, fn)` or `lapply(data, fn)`.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(ri=rep(1:20, n), v=as.vector(l))
dcast(DT, ri ~ v, length)
```

output:

```
    ri   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
 1:  1 499 506 481 507 434 498 537 493 495 474 504 506 545 499 492 467 510 527 507 519
 2:  2 506 513 473 521 520 492 508 518 469 520 491 463 495 520 499 526 502 481 492 491
 3:  3 481 499 510 480 506 499 493 522 512 507 516 484 516 482 536 476 509 477 500 495
 4:  4 502 498 519 532 493 522 481 515 542 488 471 496 466 443 460 505 531 481 532 523
 5:  5 497 468 523 492 475 430 502 491 526 514 490 528 460 498 471 557 488 547 521 522
 6:  6 514 505 497 506 533 505 482 462 536 508 482 533 505 497 527 496 479 479 479 475
 7:  7 525 522 511 476 502 536 508 486 495 452 493 506 507 498 530 498 475 478 498 504
 8:  8 544 450 521 528 491 497 534 503 504 497 506 464 485 501 511 467 478 484 523 512
 9:  9 442 515 515 507 496 515 460 537 528 510 490 500 526 510 499 508 497 517 465 463
10: 10 513 505 497 517 486 483 518 483 503 491 495 514 507 483 485 514 516 501 498 491
11: 11 480 530 491 486 503 507 517 487 467 499 504 497 496 521 499 444 525 511 500 536
12: 12 507 464 506 537 516 489 480 500 450 507 490 539 482 484 508 483 522 519 471 546
13: 13 501 527 521 443 510 527 507 507 492 547 486 465 515 544 504 472 502 529 456 445
14: 14 478 494 502 464 495 515 503 504 514 475 522 471 529 487 509 548 500 505 510 475
15: 15 489 513 488 505 532 487 506 525 438 530 534 497 494 475 491 494 468 499 544 491
16: 16 520 484 467 516 480 498 508 503 512 472 535 503 533 526 505 508 495 477 460 498
17: 17 512 465 491 514 516 469 487 485 491 465 522 550 494 514 506 542 508 476 490 503
18: 18 505 526 503 499 502 518 484 489 508 513 476 491 505 478 482 523 500 461 555 482
19: 19 528 508 492 488 513 513 493 474 500 510 467 474 463 543 482 495 523 522 505 507
20: 20 457 508 492 482 497 500 492 516 518 521 526 519 477 497 504 477 472 529 494 522
```

data:

```
set.seed(0L)
n <- 1e4
l <- replicate(n, sample(20))
```

Answer (score 1):

This took about 1.4 seconds on my two-year-old Macbook Pro (although @chinsoon12's data.table solution is far faster--about 0.04 seconds on my machine):

```
library(tidyverse)

# Fake data matrix, 20 rows x 100,000 columns
n = 100000
set.seed(2)
d = replicate(n, sample(1:20))

# Convert to long data frame and count positions
d %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=everything()) %>% 
  arrange(name) %>% 
  mutate(position = rep(1:20, n)) %>% 
  group_by(value, position) %>% 
  tally
```

> ```
>    value position     n
>    <int>    <int> <int>
>  1     1        1  4901
>  2     1        2  5031
>  3     1        3  4980
>  4     1        4  4997
>  5     1        5  4959
>  6     1        6  5004
>  7     1        7  4888
>  8     1        8  5021
>  9     1        9  4970
> 10     1       10  4986
> # … with 390 more rows
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this can be done fast, without any package:

```
n <- 10000
k <- 20
data <- replicate(n, sample(k))


## The result: a k times k array.
## E.g. result[1, 5] tells you how often 
## 5 appears in row 1.

result <- array(NA, dim = c(k, k))


for (i in 1:k) {
    tmp <- data[seq(i, to = length(data), by = k)]
    for (j in 1:k)
        result[i, j] <- sum(tmp == j)
}
```

For a million samples (`n == 1e6`), it takes about 2 seconds or so.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid growing objects in a loop and bookkeeping of initializing then assigning to objects. Consider `sapply` or slightly faster, `vapply` (that verifies the type and length return):

```
myVec <- sapply(seq(n), function(k) match(a, data[,k]))
sum(myVec==b)

myVec <- vapply(seq(n), function(k) match(a, data[,k]), integer(1))
sum(myVec==b)
```